# SVG stroke not working properly with CSS Variables

Tags: css, svg, media-queries

I'm trying to set different stroke colors for my SVG logo based on color scheme, but it doesn't want to change properly, because It'll always stay white...

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: white) {
    :root {
        --color: #000;
    }
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    :root {
        --color: #fff;
    }
}

#logo path {
    stroke: var(--color);
}
```

The thing is if I change the stroke color to any color, like for example stroke: red, it stays red...

Comment: It should be `light` not `white`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme :)

Comment: And this won't work at all on Safari.

Comment: Is it achievable in Safari?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`white` is an invalid value for `prefers-color-scheme`.

You should use:

```
prefers-color-scheme: light
```

instead of:

```
prefers-color-scheme: white
```